# RPG.Exchange Virtual Tabletop (or almost that)

Tags: discussion

Okay, bear with me for a moment (please don't use a literal bear).

We are a somewhat big community, with lots and lots of experienced gamemasters and players.

We also kinda know each other by our answers, comments and such. We know that, on average, the RPG.SE user is somewhat of a nice guy most of the time, at least, when compared to other people from other communities out there.

So, it got me thinking - We don't really *need* a blog, but it would be nice to have a "lobby" of sorts to organize and schedule games *within* this community.

Do any of you have an interest in doing something like this? Or is this just an stupid idea?

Comment: I don't pay too much attention to it, but I'm pretty sure chat is used for this purpose at times.

Comment: I would certainly use such a thing to recruit new people when needed, and perhaps to jump into the occasional impromptu game.

Comment: I'm with @diego - just open a room in chat and use that

Comment: @Wibbs No need to open a new room--in fact, it'll make the whole thing harder to work because it won't get as much visibility. [The General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) has been successful in organising games multiple times in the past.

Answer (score 13):

It's a good idea — and several of us have been using [RPG General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) for this purpose already:

- BESW used it to organise a series of RPG Stackizen Fate Accelerated games back when Fate Core/Accelerated were being playtested, based on the Enchanted Forest Chronicles.
- Grubermensch ran [a D&D 5e campaign](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=32800294#32800294) connected to the Stack Chat.
- There are several users such as Nitsua60, BESW, and Shalvenay presently running a Dungeon World game on an external service, who organised it largely from here initially.

I don't know of a convenient way to get in touch with users who don't already use chat though, other than leaving comments inviting them to chat. (Unless we use Meta sometimes to announce impending games open to community members..? IIRC some Stack sites have done stuff kinda like that.)

Comment: Agreed. (Aside: super jealous of Fate EFC, let me know if you ever revisit it!)

Comment: I’m with @SirTechSpec; I don’t think I had read the Enchanted Forest Chronicles at that point but EFC Fate sounds *amazing*.

Comment: You can read our Enchanted Forest campaign transcripts [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8403/fate-chat-and-game-room?tab=conversations); scroll toward the bottom and look for conversations that start "EF."