# Let's brainstorm some [chat] events

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-event

[Chat events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295936/311001) are a thing, I recently learned. They range from project meetings to movie nights to happy hours.

Are there ideas people have for events around here? Propose topics, time-frames (recurrence?), objectives, &c. I don't know how/whether any of this will work, but that won't stop me from trying =)

Comment: The post about scheduling, but answers are suggestions for events. Maybe we need to decide on a type of event and made another *real* scheduling post? :)

Comment: @RollingFeles that's absolutely right. And for three days--since this received a pretty-positive reception, I've been banging my head aginst *how* to schedule something. Let's say I wanted to run a LKoM session (40 min) in chat next Tuesday at 2000 UTC. Do I make a meta post? Do I create a room and schedule an event for it? Do I answer this question? I'm not really a bear of enough brain to figure out the next stage of this thing I kicked off... =(

Comment: IIRC chat has schedule tools. You can create event and it will be visible for everyone and even highlight it in a section with blog post/hot meta post. So, my thought is to talk in chat about time(and it looks like you've alredy made up your mind and just use this chat-event tool to appoint it.

Comment: @RollingFeles oh, no, that wasn't a real date-time I gave up there--it was just "for example." So maybe the best thing is just to write up a little "here's *how* to schedule a chat-event and what you can expect" post?

Comment: I have made test party room (I'm not sure if we need separate room for events or shall we do it in general chat) and this is what I see: http://imgur.com/a/6cqkI. I have added you as room owner. Try it! :)

Comment: @nitsua60 [post and sticky](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6880/23064) it in [chat], I guess?

Answer (score 15):

### Micro-RPG play/playtests

Our Very Own<sup>TM</sup> chatizens have written a number of small RPGs. (And there are hundreds of other micro-RPGs out there worth trying!) Often people will take them for a test drive, but I know I forget about them pretty quickly, since they're not often in my RL-group's rotation. But plenty are amenable to play-by-chat. Let's do it some time(s)!

---

Some that I know of:

- [COLONYPUNK](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2016/rpg/2016/04/13/COLONYPUNKaresistanceassimilationgame.html) by Our Very Own [@BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw)
- [The Duel](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2015/rpg/finalist/2015/04/01/TheDuel.html) by OVO [@Rabalais](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28881/rabalias)
- [Gotterdammerung](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2017/rpg/2017/04/20/Gtterdmmerung.html) by OVO [@Magician](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1421/magician)
- [Long Live the King of Monsters](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ccuveFwDK05dWyOqbsR6gwHuYRrt-jAv45pAUQhjEVc/edit) by OVO [@BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw)
- [Quarantine](https://200wordrpg.github.io//2017/rpg/2017/04/15/Quarantine.html) by a Stackizen
- [Shonen RPG](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2017/rpg/2017/04/17/ShonenRPG.html) by OVO [@AnneAunyme](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28479/anne-aunyme)

---

Scheduled:

- COLONYPUNK: [00:30 2 Jun 2017, hosted by nitsua60](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13/the-back-room-live-tabletop-games?tab=schedule)

Answer (score 12):

## Tabletop Tasting Time!

A lot of people visiting the chat (including myself) have awareness of only so many different RPGs, with some folks only familiar with D&D or D&D-and-friends. Let's have an evening when we discuss, review, share and raise awareness of less known but not necessarily obscure games, especially ones that are small, free and different. Obvious candidates for such tasters are Cthulhu Dark, Lady Blackbird, Great Ork Gods, Lasers and Feelings, Honey Heist, Dog Eat Dog; or if going for something larger (that we are more likely to discuss than play) Fiasco, Dogs in the Vineyard, Night Witches, Lovecraftesque, 13th Age, ...

Answer (score 5):

## Movie Night!

OK, it's entirely unoriginal. And, OK, most of the movies that are on-topic for us are terrible. But it's not like we're under any obligation to keep these events relevant to our site's purpose, and movie nights are a really fun thing.

## TV Night!

@KRyan's suggestion, and presumably easier for people to find a 20 or 40 minute time to watch an episode of something than a 2 hour slot to watch a movie.

Comment: Ooh, maybe we can schedule that [Harvey/Donnie Darko](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=36658530#36658530) double-header I've been thinking about =D

Comment: It’s not a movie and thus would be a scheduling nightmare, but the show *Stranger Things* on Netflix has a lot of D&D references in it and is quite good.

Comment: I believe over on Arqade, they make good use of the Rabb.it service for sharing a stream.  The service basically spawns a virtual instance of a browser that everybody can watch in sync.  So this allows for watching almost anything that can be streamed to a browser.  I've personally used it with YouTube movie rentals.

Comment: @KRyan That's a cool idea - I keep hearing about that show, but haven't watched it yet. Also, scheduling episode-length sessions has got to be easier than movie-length ones.

Comment: @KRyan oooh! I would *absolutely* do a re-watch with live-chat in place =)

Comment: @MadMAxJr there's one called "watch2gether" that scifi uses also.

Comment: *The Gamers* series is great. *Dorkness Rising* is probably the best for a movie night here.

Comment: @fectin That's another one I've heard mentioned a lot and never seen.

Comment: @Miniman it's low-budget but pitch-perfect.

Comment: @KRyan are you interested in hosting (or co-) a *Stranger Things* event?

Comment: @nitsua60 As much as I like the idea, no. It would be awkward with my schedule and I've just watched it fairly recently (part of why I thought of it when I saw this).

Comment: @KRyan alrighty--I may try to drum up some enthusiasm for this one, next.

Answer (score 4):

## Book Club!

Alright, I'll admit it: I've had [*Playing at the World*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15784870-playing-at-the-world) for over a year, and I'm not quite halfway through. But with your help, maybe I could make it by 2018?

Alternatively, there are (of course) hundreds of other books out there I could be pleasantly reading, if only I knew which ones they were....

Comment: Its Clausewitz time! (no dad no...)

Answer (score 3):

This is a silly one, but also a relatively little-known site...

## Let's try [Drawception](https://drawception.com)

The pitch: [draw a picture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnKZygaAjqE) from a random prompt using MS Paint level tools in 10 minutes. Someone describes your picture, and someone else draws from that description. Down it goes in a chain until everyone has either drawn something or described something.

You can create "private games" when you reach a certain level (Level 3, I believe), wherein you can invite 6, 12, or 15 people to participate in that private game.

You can see all the pictures and prompts at the end of the game. The spirit of the game is like "Pass the message" where you start with a prompt and watch the message get distorted as it goes down the line. Usually, the result is entertaining. And no, you don't have to be good at drawing.

---

Seriously, it's fun. These are recent games between newbies. Notice the intentional misreading and misinterpretations. And note that any given person only has access to the one panel (whether drawing or prompt) before them.

#### Game 1

[image]

---

#### Game between vets (people who own Wacoms and level 15+)

[image]

Comment: always heard this called "Telephone Pictionary"

Answer (score 2):

## Blog Club!

Bite-sized book club. Short enough to read and comment on in an hour or two.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy idea. I don't know how this will work, but what about...

## Let's Play [Treason](http://coup.thebrown.net/)

Someone wrote an online version of [Coup](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/131357/coup) and the designer, Rikki, [has no issues with it](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/20521965#20521965). It's quite fun even without using the chat interface (but it also has a chat interface, which is useful). For warming up, it even offers an AI mode.

Something about playing deception games is just so appealing. Give it a try!