# Chat event: COLONYPUNK

Tags: discussion, chat-event

We're [trying to schedule some [chat] events](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7099/23970).

---

### COLONYPUNK: a resistance and assimilation game

> You're LOCALS. a FOREIGN power has colonised your nation....

Thus begins [COLONYPUNK](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2016/rpg/2016/04/13/COLONYPUNKaresistanceassimilationgame.html), a 200-word RPG by Our Very Own<sup>TM</sup> [@BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw). I'll host a game, and you may [**register here** for 00:30 on 2 Jun 2017 in The Back Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13/the-back-room-live-tabletop-games?tab=schedule). (That link also contains the event info; that's UTC time. 8:30 PM Eastern US on Jun 1, if anyone cares to check my math.)

This is a GM-less game, so I'll really just play host. Please take a look at the (micro-sized) ruleset before coming, and register (at the link above) if only so I can see what difference that makes =)

---

Spectators welcome!

---

Chat transcript: [part I (2 Jun 2017)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13/conversation/colonypunk-playtest-pt-i-the-colony)

Part II coming 9 Jun 2017 00:30 UTC. ([Register here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13/the-back-room-live-tabletop-games?tab=schedule))

Comment: How many "play slots" are you thinking? (I'm assuming spectators are welcome too!)

Comment: I have no idea? I've run C'PUNK IRL with six people, never in chat. I'll ping the author with an RfC =)

Comment: Seems to me as an open, community-wide event, it makes sense to [featured] this.

Comment: @KRyan hmm... my vague understanding was that as a chat event it'd somehow show up in the sidebar. I'll poke around--thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: This is now FEATURED. We might not do that for all of these, but I'll at least do that for this first experimental one, especially since there's only about a day left.

Comment: @doppelgreener I think we should do that for all of these.  I like to think of myself as fairly active on meta but I missed this until it was featured, despite specifically looking out for it.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer the thing is, I believe the chat-event itself, by dint of being created by a mod, was somehow supposed to feature it itself in the sidebar. I just don't know whether I didn't set that up right, or if the window's short and greener manually featured it first... knocking off the rough edges here =)

Comment: @nitsua60 It may be helpful, if there's a set ending time, to include it in the post in the future.  While I knew because of hearsay that you *expected* the game to run an hour, I was certainly not under the impression that that's how much time you had thought to allot it. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Good suggestion--I set the event time in the schedule at 60 minutes, but don't yet have a good sense of how visible those sorts of things are. (Obviously not visible enough!)